# Qmail. Send email from Maildir\new folder

Tags: email, qmail, maildir

I have a bunch of emails within .../Maildir/new folder. How to send them via qmail?

Also maybe you can advise how to block all emails from specific domain? I've tried to block using control/badmailfrom file, but seems that it doesn't work

```
.*\ @.*
!.*@.*\..*
.*%.*
@domain.com
```

Thanks in advance,
Nick

Answer (score 0):

The answer how to send emails from /Maildir/new folder below:

Create a new script:

```
for file in /var/vpopmail/domains/.../username/Maildir/new/* ; do
qmail-inject -f mail@domain.com -a wheretosend@domain.com <"$file"
done
```

And execute it: # bash script_name